# Error cannot convert return to type uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

i used [TYPagerController](https://github.com/12207480/TYPagerController) , i trying to show view controller and i have an error

> cannot convert return expression of type [uiviewcontroller] to return type 'UIViewController'

```
func tabPagerController(_ tabPagerController: TYTabPagerController, controllerFor index: Int, prefetching: Bool) -> UIViewController {
  let storyboardName = "Main"
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: Bundle.main)
    var viewControllers = [UIViewController]()
        let categoryCV = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeToCategory") as! CategoryViewController
            viewControllers.append(categoryCV)
        let featuredCV = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FeatureViewController") as! featuredViewController
            viewControllers.append(featuredCV)

    return viewControllers
}
```

Comment: The func is waiting for 1 viewcontroller and you are returning an array of viewcontrollers

Comment: `[UIViewController]` That's an array of `UIViewController` objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for in this case is simply:

`return viewControllers[index]`

Just ensure the number of view controllers in `numberOfControllersInTabPagerController` delegate function is 2 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your function is programmed to return 1 ViewController `-> UIViewController`. What you are doing is returning an array of ViewControllers thus the error is encountered `return viewControllers`.

Either change your function to return an array of ViewControllers or return 1 View Controller.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, your function's return type is **UIViewController**

```
func tabPagerController(_ tabPagerController: TYTabPagerController, controllerFor index: Int, prefetching: Bool) -> UIViewController {
```

but you are returning **viewControllers** which is an array of UIViewController

```
var viewControllers = [UIViewController]()
```

Either change the return type of your function or do a little more conditional coding on which UIViewController you want to return.